# Como faço para pausar uma musica no python?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, pygame

Consigo fazer o programa reproduzir a musica, porem toda a janela fica sem funçao e so volta a funcionar quando a musica para, ou seja mesmo criando um botao com def para pausar o botao so se torna "clicavel" quando a musica toda parar.

```
from tkinter import *
from pygame import *
from pygame import mixer
jan = Tk()
jan.title("JANELAA")
jan.geometry('400x400')

class Sistema:
   def __init__(self, box):
    self.frame = Frame(box)
    self.frame.pack()
    self.menu = Menu(box)
    self.menuFile = Menu(self.menu)
    self.menuFile.add_command(label="Musicas" , command=self.msc)
    self.menuFile.add_command(label="Notepad")
    self.menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=self.menuFile)
    self.menuOption = Menu(self.menu)
    self.menuOption.add_command(label="Calculadora")
    self.menu.add_cascade(label="Options" , menu=self.menuOption)
    box.config(menu=self.menu)

def msc(self):
    lbl = Label(jan, text="MUSICA COLD BLOODED")
    lbl.place(x=50, y=50)

    def ok():
        mixer.init()
        mixer.music.load('coldb.mp3')
        mixer.music.play(1 , 1)
        while mixer.music.get_busy():
            time.Clock().tick(10)

    bt = Button(jan, text="TOCAR", command=ok)
    bt.place(x=50, y=70)
Sistema(jan)
jan.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que esteja faltando a verificação de eventos, já que o `event.get()` sem ser chamado a tela irá ficar congelada.

```
def ok():
    mixer.init()
    mixer.music.load('coldb.mp3')
    mixer.music.play(1 , 1)
    musica_tocando = True
    while mixer.music.get_busy():
        time.Clock().tick(10)
        for event in event.get()
            if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if musica_tocando: 
                    mixer.music.pause()
                    musica_tocando = False
                else:
                    mixer.music.unpause() 
                    musica_tocando = True
```

Comment: Cara vlw o programa agr nao precisa mais ter que esperar a musica acabar, porem ainda estou com dificuldades para criar o botao de pause, nao entendo como o evento MOUSEBUTTONDOWN: diz que é pra pausar porem nao existe nenhum botao de pause, e tive de adicionar um -> : <- depois do envent.get() mas da um erro no interpretador mas desde ja agradeço pois o problema que estava dando foi resolvido

Comment: Tipo o botao pause que criei ele nao so pausa ele para toda a musica e nao volta mais quando clico no msm botao de iniciar, devo criar um botao e aplicar funçoes para voltar de onde parou?

Comment: Cara, tive que criar 3 botoes
1º Botao para Tocar
2º Botao para pausar
3º Botao para Despausar
agr o unico erro que diz é do : dois pontos que add dps do event.get() mas o programa ta rodando

Comment: o erro foi o seguinte:
for event in event.get() :
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'event' referenced before assignment

Comment: Tenta ver se o erro não é de identação. A referência ao event tem que estar dentro do loop "for", senão o interpretador não "acha" ele.